# Post to wall as Facebook App (not as a user)?

Tags: facebook, oauth

I need to obtain an access_token *as* an App, not as an admin or user. This is so that I can post/comment/like in a the style of "[ app name ] has commented on your post".

The problem is that when I attempt to get an access token (which I do successfully), I'm getting one that is for me (the admin) because I'm logged in when I attempt to call:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[app id]&redirect_uri=[url]&scope=publish_stream,offline_access&type=user_agent&display=popup

What is the process for getting an non-expiring access token AS an app, rather than an admin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An application is not a user. It only acts on behalf of users. Consider creating a [page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) for your application and posting such things as the page.

Perhaps I'm not understanding the desire for your app to be its own being.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed a lot about posting as a Page. I'm thinking that may end up being the only route I can take. I find it hard to believe an Application cannot create Posts on its behalf. Seems strange, no?

Comment: Not particularly. An app is not a user of facebook. An app is a tool that users use.