# [facebook]Can I post message to wall from apps using page user?

Tags: facebook

I want to post some message to wall using my app.
But for some reason,  my users want to show the page name instead of user name in the wall.
I thought maybe I can use [use facebook as page] menu.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901316/post-to-wall-as-facebook-app-not-as-a-user
But I was wrong. In that case I can't use my app in canvas page.
I saw the youtube app.They can post the message as page user.
http://apps.facebook.com/videobox/pages
Do I miss something?
Any idea will be help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to publish to a Page's wall?  Your app will need the following 2 extended permissions from the user:

- publish_stream
- manage_pages

With those two permissions, you can first get a list of all of the pages that the user is an admin of, along with the Page's access tokens as follows:

GET URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={user_access_token}

Once you have the Page's access_token, you can now Publish to the Page's wall as follows:

```
POST URL: https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed
POST BODY: access_token={page_access_token}&message=Test+Post
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: JohnnyO, Thank you for you responds. I did the same way just like you said. I used the user_access_token.  I couldn't get the access_token for the page user. And, I got user name in the wall.  Is there anyway I can get Page's access_token?? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the user's manage_pages permission?  If yes, what do you see when you call this API? https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token={user_access_token}

Comment: Thank you for your information!
 I did exactly what you said. But I still got user name in my page.
 Last night，I checked the facebook Graph API document. 
I found out that I can get the page_user_access_token using user_access_token.
Just like this.
https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=user_access_token 
$Then, I tried to post some message using page_user_access_token like you told me.
And, I did it!
Now, I can post messages to my wall using my page name!
Thank you so much！！